# Why do I lose selected item of RadComboBox within a repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, repeater

I'm using a `RadComboBox` with `AutoPastback` enabled within a repeater which data is filled by a `LinqDataSource`.
Everything works fine except when I select an item from `RadComboBox`.
After postback the selected of item `RadComboBox` is disappeared and cleared just like nothing is selected.

Code :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource4" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" OnItemCreated="Repeater1_ItemCreated">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table class="expertMode">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox66" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" EmptyMessage="نام صفت مثل : رنگ"  DataTextField="Key" DataValueField="Key" AllowCustomEntry="True"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: @StefanH my page load in code behind is completely unused.

Comment: Are you selecting with javascript or by clicking with the mouse?

Comment: @AndrewWalters Selecting with clicking mouse. You got any idea ?

Comment: Sorry I got nothing, there's some tricks you have to do sometimes when using javascript. Good luck figuring it out. Post up the answer when you get something, I'd like to see what the problem is

Comment: @Mahdi, was this ever solved. I am having the same problem, and I'm curious if you solved the problem.

Comment: @RLH I really don't remember what happened two years ago. But because I have not answered question then I guess it wasn't solved.